# Table view load subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

When a user clicks on a Table View Cell, I would like to push a UIView into the place of the Table View, swap out the current top bar items to just have a "back" button to return to the original view, and remove the bottom bar. How could I do that?

Here is structure:

[image]

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what is should look like after a table view cell is clicked:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is your view in `UInavigationController`?

Comment: If you want to implement some kind of navigation I think it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want the exact behaviour of a `UINavigationController`. Take a look at the docs:
[UINavigationController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS (Navigation Controllers)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `UINavigationController` that manages 2 `UIViewController`s (one for each of the views you described above). Then to push and pop (go back and forward in the navigation) use

`self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL)`

and

`self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)`